# Not on the same exact page of the book, but on the other page that the book is open to?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say I have a book open, and the page on the left is A and the page on the right is B. There is a picture of me on page B. I'm pointing out to my friend over text that there is a picture of her on page A, but I'm highlighting the fact that we're both on the same page! But not literally on the same page. Just, you can see both of us when you are turned to this page. I can't say "you're on the previous page" because it might mean you have to flip back a page to see her picture, which isn't as special. I can't say "We're next to each other!" because that's not very correct, there are other people on the page that I am on.

How do I word this? Is there a word for this? "We're on the same ____ of the book!"

Comment: Graphic designers might call this a two-page spread. So you could say, we're on the same "spread."

Comment: Opposite or facing page. You are both on the same spread.

Comment: Hopefully one of the two pages is on the right.

Comment: Haha, just noticed that too, @aparente001. Fixed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One possibility is **spread**.

From [Michigan State University Libraries](http://libguides.lib.msu.edu/c.php?g=97090&p=908734):

> When you open a book anywhere, you’ll see two pages: a left-hand page
>   and a right-hand page, which face each other. These two pages together
>   are called a **spread**.
>
> Each section of your book should start on a right-hand page. The title
>   page is always a right-hand page, the table of contents begins on a
>   right-hand page, chapter 1 begins on a right-hand page, and so on.
>
> Book designers call these two pages by the Latin terms “recto” for the
>   right-hand page and “verso” for the reverse or left-hand page. This
>   usage may help you remember that each new section always starts on the
>   recto or right-hand page, not on the ‘reverse’.

Your example:

> "We're on the same **spread** of the book!"

**If you'd prefer a more familiar term**, you could say:

> "We're on **opposite** pages of the book!"
>
> "We're on **opposed** pages of the book!"
>
> "We're on **adjacent** pages of the book!"

Take your pick. :-) My favorite is "We're on **opposite** pages of the book!"

Note: I acknowledge that the comments on the question mention **spread**, as does @alwayslearning's answer. I didn't see either prior to submitting my answer.

Answer (score 28):

You may say:

> "We're on ***facing pages*** of the book!"

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/facing+pages):

> *Noun*
>   1.    **facing pages** - two facing pages of a book or other publication
>
> *also* **spread head, spreadhead, spread**

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/facing):

> **facing** 
>   *ADJECTIVE* [ATTRIBUTIVE]
>
> Positioned so as to face:
>   **two facing pages**
>
> Indeed, Sheth has arranged the images in such a way that you see two
>   different worlds on facing pages.
>
> Sadly, this information is not on the facing pages of the catalog I
>   got, but maybe it's hidden in the text somewhere.

Note: It is acknowledged that the terms facing page & spread are already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Do you need to acknowledge something was mentioned in comments? If they wanted to get the rep, they should have written an answer not a comment. (In fact, they should have anyway, because *you shouldn't answer in comments...*)

Comment: *Facing pages*. Excellent result for two friends. Nicely done. +1